# How can I undo the latest git command in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm not sure what the heck I did, but I for some reason had a "`HEAD`" and a "`MASTER`" branch. And my latest commit only had "`HEAD`", so I tried figuring out how to change it to MASTER. I went to `VCS` > `Git` > `Branches`, and I think I pressed out "checkout" on the `MASTER` branch. Now, my whole project reverted to that `MASTER` branch and I lost a LOT of progress.

**Now my question is**, how can I undo this? I haven't done ANYTHING since that happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the wonderful <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> did the trick. This UNDOs your latest thing you did, so if you did anything after this I won't guarantee this will work.